# Move payment options at checkout in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using WooCommerce and i'm new to both Wordpress and this plugin. I have downloaded a free theme which I will configure, however I can't figure out how I can change the checkout template. What I want to do is moving payment options from bottom, to the top right column.

http://bildr.no/image/SWtmTlZo.jpeg

Which files do I need to edit?

Comment: This question is generic in the sense that it's not clear what is the approach, but it is very specific to Wordpress indeed.

Answer (score 7):

You can customize the checkout page using hooks.
To remove the payment options add the following code to your (child)theme's functions.php:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20 );
```

To add it after the order notes use this hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20 );
```

Comment: Perfect! I tried to move the template parts, but then they don't have the correct variables available. Like this, you can change the entire structure!